# Need to create a file editor that rearranges file lines

Tags: java, data-manipulation

I'm trying to build a program that reads a file and rearranges the lines so that it is 'correct'. This text file is created by a third party but the lines are out of order and once they are in order, another program can read it. I'm not creating the file or using it after I edit it. This program would be a bridge between two ends of a workflow. Currently my boss is a big fan of Java but I'm not sure this programming language would be best for the goal in mind. I haven't started any serious coding for this venture but I'm considered a beginner in java so before I go crazy trying to overcome the learning curve I figured I'd ask the community.

My question is: for file manipulation (as described above) would Java be the best choice?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What does 'correct' mean in your context? Do you want to sort the lines or something? Can you give an example?
In my opinion, if you want to sort the lines (e.g. alphabetically or by an index at the start of the line or something) it can be done quiet easily in Java.

Comment: *"My question is: for file manipulation (as described above) would Java be the best choice?*" - That's a matter of opinion

Comment: how large is the file? whats the "correct" order?

Comment: Sorry I didn't comment any sooner. Right now I have lines that are out of order. Let's say dog, cat, and fish were in a column. I don't want them alphabetized or an established pattern like that. I have a pattern that I want them to be in : fish cat dog. It seems, based on the answer from Bethany that I probably need to be looking into ArrayLists as a possible avenue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution here depends on what you're trying to do, and I can only guess at what that might be without more information provided. As Thomas Bohm said in his comment, it depends on what "correct" means here. I'll offer help for some possibilities; assume for each that each example is working with plaintext files.

One possibility is each file line is prefixed with something. Consider this example:

```
Name: John Doe
Phone: (555) 555-5555
Email: jdoe@example.com
```

Let's say that each entry should be formatted like this, with one empty line between each separate entry. In the files you're dealing with, each entry contains a name, phone number, and email, but not necessarily in the right order.

In this case, you would want to create a class (let's name it Entry in this example) to store the information in each entry. Each instance of it should have three String variables - name, phone, and email. You would then want to create an ArrayList in your main class and create each entry as such (note that sc is a Scanner reading the .txt file):

```
ArrayList<Entry> entries = new ArrayList<>();
String[] info = new String[3];
String name;
String phone;
String email;

while (sc.hasNextLine()) {

    do {
        info[0] = sc.nextLine();
    } while (!sc.nextLine().isEmpty());
    // this ensures that empty lines will not be treated as if they contained information

    info[1] = sc.nextLine();
    info[2] = sc.nextLine();
    // all three lines in the entry have now been assigned to Strings

    for (int i=0; i<3; i++) {
        if (info[i].startsWith("Name") {
            name = info[i];
        } else if (info[i].startsWith("Phone") {
            phone = info[i];
        } else if (info[i].startsWith("Email") {
            email = info[i];
        }
    }

    entries.add(new Entry(name, phone, email));
}
```

You then might want to write a `toString()` method within the Entry class that would return an Entry as a String formatted the proper way, then write a method in your main class to iterate over the ArrayList and write the contents of each to a file.

Keep in mind that this assumes each entry in the text file contains each of the three pieces of information necessary, each on a separate consecutive line, and each prefix is included (with correct spelling and capitalization). The output file would end up with incorrect information if any of these three lines were omitted or not correctly prefixed.

For the second possible example, consider a case the same as before but without the prefixes at the start of each line, as such:

```
John Doe
(555) 555-5555
jdoe@example.com
```

If this is the case, I would advise familiarizing yourself with regular expressions. The code for this would be very similar to the previous code, except that the conditional statements would be matching the entire String info[i] to regular expressions such as those below:

Name: `^[A-Z][a-z]+ ([A-Z][a-z]* )?[A-Z][a-z]+$` (allows for first name, optional middle name or initial, and last name, with proper capitalization, spacing, and no punctuation)

Phone: `^\(\d{3}\) \d{3}-\d{4}$` (matches any phone number in (555) 555-5555 format)

Phone: `^\(?(\d{3})?\W{0,2}\d{3}-?\d{4}$` (matches any 7-digit or 10-digit phone number; parentheses, spacing, and hyphenation optional)

Email: `^\w+@\w+\..+$` (matches any valid email address)

You could then test if a String matches a given regular expression like such:

```
info[i].matches("^\w+@\w+\..+$")
```

This would return `true` if `info[i]` is a valid email address; otherwise, `false`.

Now, let's say you need your program to do something completely different, such as alphabetizing the lines in a file. In this case, you would want to create an ArrayList and store each line in the file as a String in this ArrayList. You would then want to sort this list alphabetically and write the sorted list to a file.

I don't have time to write the code for this case now, but I can help you with this later if this is your goal here.

Comment: Thanks for the indepth response. It was definitely helpful! I think I need to go towards ArrayLists (see previous comment on original post) to solve my issue. 'Correct' just means I have a pattern that I would like the lines to fit into and no obvious way (like alphabetical or numerical) that I can go about rearranging the file.